# MongooseError [ValidatorError]: Path `encry_password` is required

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

Hii people i am new in node js ,i am getting an error while testing code through postman encry_password is required dont know where i am wrong please check and fix my error

> user/model   here is my user model where i define my all schema that i am using in my appliaction

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');

//const Schema = new mongoose.Schema();

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 32,
        trim: true
    },
    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxlength: 32,
        trim: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
        unique: true
    },
    userinfo: {
        type: String,
        trim: true
    },
    encry_password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    salt: String,
    role: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    purchases: {
        type: Array,
        default: []
    }
},
    {
        timestamps: true
    });

userSchema.virtual('password')
    .set(function (password) {
        this._password = password
        this.salt = uuidv1();
        this.secure_password = this.securePassword(password);
    })
    .get(function () {
        return this._password
    })

userSchema.methods = {

    autheticate: function (plainpassword) {
        return this.securePassword(plainpassword) === this.secure_password
    },

    securePassword: function (plainpassword) {
        if (!plainpassword) {
            return "";
        }
        try {
            return crypto.createHmac('sha256', this.salt)
                .update(plainpassword)
                .digest('hex');
        }
        catch (err) {
            return "";
        }
    }
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

> Auth.js

here is my auth controller where i define my signup logic   please check what is wrong here and

```
 const User = require("../models/user")
    const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');
    
    //SIGNUP VALIDATION
    exports.signup = (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(422).json({
                error: errors.array()[0].msg
            })
        }
        console.log('req.body: ',req.body)
        const user = new User(req.body)
        user.save((err, user) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log("ERROR:",err)
                return res.status(400).json({
                    err: "not able to connect"
                });
            }
            res.json({
                name: user.name,
                lastname: user.lastname,
                email: user.email,
                id: user._id,
                password:user.password
            });
        });
    
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You define an `encry_password` field and set it to `required:true` in your schema but in your logic, you didn't provide a value for the `encry_password`, the error is just showing you that the named field can't be empty.
Try refactoring your code to look like the one below:

```
//SIGNUP VALIDATION
exports.signup = (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(422).json({
            error: errors.array()[0].msg
        })
    }
    console.log('req.body: ',req.body)
    // do this instead
    const userDetails = {
     name: req.body.name,
     email: req.body.email,
     lastname:req.body.lastname,
     userInfo:req.body.userInfo,
     salt:req.body.salt
     encry_password:req.body.password
     } 

    const user = new User(userDetails)
    user.save().then((user) => {
          res.json({
            name: user.name,
            lastname: user.lastname,
            email: user.email,
            id: user._id,
            password:user.password
        });    
    }).catch(err=>{
       if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR:",err)
            return res.status(400).json({
                err: "not able to connect"
            });
        }
     });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You define an encry_password field and its required: true in your schema but in your Parameters, you didn't provide an encry_password.

so There is Two way to resolve this error.

```
  1 ->
    remove  required: true from your schema.
  2->
    You must need to provide encry_password field in req.body.
```

Answer (score 0):

can you also put here the values as you were entering in postman.So i can give you the answer